# How do I generate a list of 4 digits pins and then use them before generating more in my ASP.NET Core web application and C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm working on a carpark keypad system which uses 4 digit codes to let the customers in.  Part of that system requires the generation of pin numbers that are 4 digits long.  I created a very simply way of doing this in C# however, more capability is needed to prevent (potentially) the same pin being issued more than one before it's been used.

To address this issue I thought it would be best to generate a list of say 50 pins which are all 4 digits long, at random, then remove them from the list as they were displayed to the user on the client side.  Then once those 50 pins had been returned to the user, generate another 50 pins.

Here is my very simple code that generates a pin.  `PinGeneration` is called from the client side via JavaScript.

```
public class PinController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Random random = new Random();

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }        
        public IActionResult PinGeneration() 
        {
            var num = random.Next(1000, 9999);
            return Json(num);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me achieve this task of generating 50 pins, displaying a pin from that list of 50 to the user when it's requested and removing it so it can't be used again until all 50 pins have been used?

In my mind I see a `List<int>` that I can simple call `Remove` on but I'm not sure how to apply it here.

many thanks

Comment: Do you plan to store the already generated pins in a database? And also do you want the pins to be not sequential?

Comment: Long terms yes, but right now, no.  I was considering using sessions  or even local storage.

Comment: So what would happen if your application crashes and restarts? All pins that were given out would suddenly be invalid? Or suddenly duplicates could be given out? Also when the previous visitor gets the last pin of the set of 50, what is stopping me from receiving a duplicate?

Comment: Why is it a problem that multiple users potentially have identical PINs?